# Python 3 decimal module and limiting Decimal length

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

Just moving from 2.7 to 3.4 I ran into this issue with decimal:

I'm trying to replicate SQL numeric data type with `decimal` module.
In 2.7, I did this:

```
def copy_ctx(places, prec):
    res = DefaultContext.copy()
    res.prec = places
    res.Emin = res.Emax = places - prec - 1
    return res
```

This effectively limited any resulting `Decimal`s to specified number of places or less.
Trying to instantiate a number too large would yield an `OverflowError`.
For example:

```
x = Decimal(1000000, copy_ctx(5,2))  # Error! number is too much
x = Decimal(100, copy_ctx(5,2))  # == 100.00
```

However, In Python 3.4, `decimal` won't let me set Emin to a positive number.

How can I achieve the same behaviour as in 2.7?

Comment: I'd have considered allowing a positive Emin as a bug in Python 2.7, really. Using it to set an upper limit on the integer part is.. creative.

Comment: The limit is enforced in the [new C optimisations](http://bugs.python.org/issue7652); the only way around that would be to disable the `_decimal` module (e.g. remove it from your installation altogether). **Not** recommended. I don't yet see an alternative route here.

Comment: What do you mean "creative"? Is there another way of setting maximum number of digits a Decimal can take?

Comment: I meant that that use case was never considered in the design of the library, `Emin` was only ever meant to be 0 or smaller. The fact that it worked at all was lucky. :-) No, I do not know of another way.

Comment: The Py3 decimal doc now has this: "Emin must be in the range [MIN_EMIN, 0], Emax in the range [0, MAX_EMAX]."

Comment: This effectively means I have to add .quantize and range checks to every single operation whereas previously that was all done by Context...

Answer (score 0):

Well, ultimately even the 2.7 version of `decimal` module wasn't exactly SQL Numeric friendly. I had to check every single result against my desired context. I have now added an additional quantization step in the class constructor.